# start multiple java programs (multiple JVM) from one command

Tags: java, batch-file, jvm

I want to start multiple java programs (multiple JVM) from one command.

Ex: I have two different application(lets say A and B) which solve their job independently. Now instead of running these two application separately in form of two JVM i want to bundle these two into another application or module (lets say CC). So if i start C this should start A and B in two separate window or jvm so that i can release or deploy only one module C in stead of A and B separately.

please guide me how to do that.

Thanks
Santosh

Comment: Did you investigate multi threading?

Comment: Any code so far? What have you tried?

Comment: What kind of application is that ? Stand alone, WEB, EAR ???

Comment: Multi threading is there already in the app A and B. App A is Server which handles 1000 of client parallel in 1000s thread. It treats each client in a separate thread and its going good.

Comment: Both A and B are stand alone application.

Comment: A and B app has their own .bat to invoke. So i created one more batch for C and tried to call both A and B from C which starts the very first app A only and it stays there only. Its not starting the B app in another JVM.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, this is a windows question, and you are already using a batch file to start your app, so use the [`start`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc770297.aspx) command in a batch file (check [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/198525/how-can-i-execute-a-windows-command-line-in-background) for more details):

```
start java YourClassA arg1 arg2 ...
start java YourClassB arg1 arg2 ...
```

If using linux/unix write a shell script and add `&` to the end of the java startup lines, (check [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103731/run-a-command-without-making-me-wait) for details):

```
java YourClassA arg1 arg2 &
java YourClassB arg1 arg2 &
```

You can also create a java class `C` that uses the [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to start the two other programs (apparently an overkill for you problem). Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17216049/executing-two-commands-with-process-builder) if you want to do that.